# Trying to create a DLL that will read a file value and return it

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to create a DLL in any language (using Visual Studio is preferred), that will read a value from a file (file will only have that single value) and then return it in the function. I am not very familiar with DLLs and I'm not quite sure how they work, but I need this for my project, any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is not Homework Support Center.

Comment: Do you have to be mean about it? If somebody wants to help, they will. You do not have to just ruin my mood by being mean. You are correct, nonetheless, what you said was unnecessary.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of this site. You didn't even do basic research into your homework - a trivial Google search brings up thousands of tutorials about how to do this. You decided to waste a number of people's time by posting what's effectively a work order. People helping others on this site do it in their free time and the time spent on postings like this could be used for helping people who are actually trying to solve problems. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did search it on google and spent about 3 hours only on youtube videos, but all of them say different things and use different methods. All I am looking for here is a general direction that I should take. Information about DLLs is so different, really every youtube video has different method. I was overwhelmed and that is why I asked for help here, if peaople do not want to help and waste time on this, it's ok, but if someone does, help would be very welcome

Comment: And also this is not for homework, I am making a project for blind people to be able to play board games in computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will be in C# (Part of Visual Studio Community Edition)

Create a class library project & include the following method in your class:

```
public static string getText(string filePath) 
{
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
         using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fs))
         {
             return tr.ReadToEnd();
         }
     }
}
```